# How can I find the gradient vector for this function?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

$ x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$

How can I find the gradient vector of $f(x,y,z)$ at $(1,1,1)$?

Can I rewrite the equation by just moving everything to one side? 
So: $x^4 - x^2 + y^4 -y^2 +z^4 -z^2 = 0$ Then find the partial derivatives?

I get <2,2,2> as a result.

Comment: Well, before you can differentiate $f$, you have to say what $f$ *is*...

Comment: but that function is f. It is a rounded cube if graphed on a 3D plotter. I'm not sure how to find the gradient at (1,1,1) though.

Comment: First, you have not defined $f$... You say 'that function is f', but what is 'that function'?

Comment: My result is $[-14, -14, -14]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. I'm assuming you got a gradient
$$\nabla f=\langle 4x^3-2x,4y^3-2y,4z^3-2z\rangle$$

and plugged in the point $(1,1,1)$, which is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the answer I was hoping for!

Comment: But how do you know what $f$ is?

Comment: It's a common thing in multivariable calculus (how I was taught it at least) just move everything to one side of the equation and call that $f$.

Comment: But that makes a result undefined! You could 'just move everything' to another side thus reversing the resulting vector. However the gradient vector points the direction of the function's **growth**, you can't just flip it at will... You might also easily multiply the sides by a constant, thus changing the vector length – but the gradient shows, how fast the function grows, you can't just extend it or shrink it. In short: you don't know the function $f$. The equation given defines the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ only, and that's simply **not enough** to calculate $\nabla f$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition

$$ x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$$

defines a $0$-level surface of a function

$$f(x,y,z)=C(x^4 - x^2 + y^4 -y^2 +z^4 -z^2)$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary non-zero constant.

The gradient vector at $(1,1,1)$ is then

$$(C,C,C).$$

Comment: How do you know what $f$ function is? The given equation is equivalent to $$ -7x^4 - 7y^4 - 7z^4 = -7x^2 - 7y^2 - 7z^2$$ which makes, with your method, $$f(x,y,z)=-7x^4 + 7x^2 - 7y^4 + 7y^2 -7z^4 + 7z^2$$ and then the gradient vector is $(-14,-14,-14)$, not $(1,1,1)$. How do you know which one is 'correct'...?!

Comment: @CiaPan: You are right. The level surface at $0$ does not define the function. A multiplier can always be applied. So edit I my answer.